# Squid proxy cluster with multiple virtual IP

Tags: squid, virtual-ip-address, corosync

I configured a clustered Squid Proxy server in CentOS 7 using Corosync, Pacemaker and PCS
I have two servers in cluster server01 and server02. Both server has one IP each. They are in the above mentioned cluster with two Virtual IPs *virtual_ip* and *virtual_ip2*. So, crm_mon output is as below:

```
Stack: corosync
Current DC: server02 (version 1.1.18-11.el7_5.3-2b07d5c5a9) - partition with quorum
Last updated: Sun Sep  2 12:43:38 2018
Last change: Thu Aug 30 14:12:24 2018 by root via cibadmin on server01

2 nodes configured
3 resources configured

Online: [ server01 server02 ]

Active resources:

 Resource Group: ProxyAndIP
     virtual_ip (ocf::heartbeat:IPaddr2):       Started server02
     squid      (ocf::heartbeat:Squid): Started server02
virtual_ip2     (ocf::heartbeat:IPaddr2):       Started server01
```

I want to use both the virtual IPs of the cluster, in Squid proxy for better HA, load balancing and there by defining different access control lists and policies. Is that possible? If it is possible, how to achieve the same?

Answer (score -1):

You have to add virtual_ip2 to the group ProxyAndIP
That should do and you can sequence them accordingly so that their start and stop order is controlled:

```html
Resource Group: ProxyAndIP
     virtual_ip (ocf::heartbeat:IPaddr2):       Started server02
     squid      (ocf::heartbeat:Squid): Started server02
     virtual_ip2     (ocf::heartbeat:IPaddr2):       Started server02
```